# Aggregate groups of data points

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My data set contains thousands of points, each with a timestamp. I want to query the database for all points, average the values of the points to get a set of points where each single point represents the average values for all points taken during the same hour.

For example, say my points are (in format `[time, value]`) are `[5:15, 10]`, `[5:20, 12]`, `[5:45, 14]`, and `[6:00, 11]`, I would want to compute a set `[[5:00, 12], [6:00, 11]]`

Is there any elegant way to achieve this with django querysets, or will I need to do many smaller queries aggregating over each hour and construct the final list manually?

EDIT: models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    temp_data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    humidity_data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    node = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Node {} - Time {}'.format(self.node, self.timestamp)
```

I would want to do this aggregation for both the temp_data and humidity_data values

Thanks

Comment: I want to know how did you compute the set `[[5:00, 12], [6:00, 11]]`, and I think the Model code is needed.

Comment: Added model code. Also, the `[[5:00, 12], [6:00, 11]]` is the average value for all data points stamped from 5:00-5:59 (i.e. (10 + 12 + 14) / 3 = 12), timestamped at the beginning of the hour (5:00) and the average for all points from 6:00-6:59 (11 / 1) stamped with 6:00... Does that make sense?

Comment: Are all your time stamps belong to the same day? Or do you need to filter them also by date?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is gonna work but give it a try. *(this will eventually only work on a daily basic e.g. 0-24h period)*

```
Entry.objects.filter(
    timestamp__date=datetime.date.today()
).values('timestamp__hour').annotate(
    AVG('temp_data'), 
    AVG('humidity_data')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately DB engine can't provide this logic, you have to do this yourself.

you can start your logic with the following code:

```
entry_query_set = Entry.objects.all().filter_by("timestamp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for a case, when all data points belong to the same day.

First, order the data by time to get the smallest and greatest times. Then calculate averages in a loop by the hours.

```
orderedEntries = Entry.objects.all().filter_by("timestamp")
minHour = orderedEntries.first().hour
maxHour = orderedEntries.last().hour
res = set()
for hour in range(minHour, maxHour + 1):
    hourEntries = Entry.objects.filter(timestamp__hour = hour)
    sum = 0
    for entry in hourEntries:
        sum += entry.node
    average = sum / len(hourEntries)
    res.add(['%s:00' % hour, average])
```

The `res` set will contain the average data values by hours:

```
set([['5:00', 12], ['6:00', 11]])
```

If the data points can belong to different days, the result must be calculated in a double loop: by date (from min to max), and by hours (from 0 to 23).